# Print Multiple Delimiters Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print out all the prime numbers between two numbers that the user has input. I can print out of the delimiters but I'm struggling on how to print out multiple and then repeat until all the prime numbers have been printed.
For example, the delimiters are "colon, exclamation point, comma". Looking for something like: 7:11!13,17:19!23​

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "));
num_2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "));
num_3 = 0

if num_2 > num_1:
     num_3 = num_1
     num_1 = num_2
     num_2 = num_3

for num in range(num_1, num_2 +1):
     if num > 1:
         for i in range(2,num):
             if (num%i) == 0:
                break
          else:
              print(num, sep="", end=","
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "));
num_2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "));
num_3 = 0

if num_2 > num_1:
     num_3 = num_1
     num_1 = num_2
     num_2 = num_3

ite_list = [":","!",","]
outa = []
for num in range(num_1, num_2 +1):
     if num > 1:
         for i in range(2,num):
             if (num%i) == 0:
                break
          else:
              outa.append(str(num) + ite_list[len(outa)%3])
outa = "".join(outa)
print(outa)
```

like that?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the delimiter before the last number? For example, when I run the code above, there will be a delimiter after the last number has been printed.

Comment: indeed there is print the string like 'print(outa[:-1])'

Answer (score 1):

You may use [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

For example:

```
import itertools
my_delimiters = itertools.cycle(":!,.")

# rest of the code

print(num, end=next(my_delimiters))
```